# Access iPhone Home Screen Background

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, homescreen

I was wondering how I could access the iPhone's Home Screen Image so that I can use it as the background for my application. In short, access the NSImage that represents the home screen's wallpaper.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, on an iDevice, it is a `UIImage`. Secondly, in answer to your question, no - not using public APIs at least.

Comment: Do you think you can recommend some kind of image or tile for an application background ? There is no table view in it, it is mainly just a text field and a progress bar (game)

Comment: I'd suggest a white or light gray background.

Comment: Alexandre, could you accept my answer please? (I know it doesn't _quite_ answer your question, but it's as close as one can get!)